# How do I solve this equation with ln(x)?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

$$1 - \dfrac{1}{x} + \ln x = 0$$

I know that the solution is $1$, because I started from the assumption that $ \ln(1)=0$. However, we cannot take this assumption for granted.

So what are the steps to solve this logarithmic function?

Comment: I am not seeing any finite sequence of steps.  But, if you wanted to have something more systematic than the guess you presented, here is a way to think about it: the equation can be rewritten in the form
$$
x = {1 \over 1 + \ln(x)}.
$$
Therefore, you are *looking for fixed points of the function*
$$
f(x) = {1 \over 1 + \ln(x)},
$$
or of its inverse, whichever domains that inverse might be defined in.

If you find that either $f(x)$ or a suitable inverse are a contraction, you can use use the fact that repeated applications of a contraction converge to the fixed point.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = 1-{1 \over x} + \log x$ on $(0,\infty)$.

Note that $f'(x) >0$, $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} f(x) = -\infty$, $\lim_{x \to + \infty} f(x) = \infty$, so we know there is a unique solution.

In this case, we can try some standard values such as $f(1) = 0$. Hence $1$ is the unique solution.

Comment: Your first limit should be going to $0^+$, not $-\infty$.

Comment: @Ian: Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

$$1+ \ln x = \frac{1}{x}$$

If $x>1$, $1+\ln x > 1$ but $\frac{1}{x} <1$.

If $x<1$, $1+\ln x<1$ but $\frac{1}{x}>1$.

Hence $x=1$ is the unique solution.

Comment: This is still "guess-and-check", it just has the advantage of checking that nothing was missed. Probably just about any solution will be guess-and-check, though, because I think if you replace the first $1$ with, say, $2$ the solution becomes much more elusive (so the problem is sensitive to the particular numeric data at hand).

Comment: True. LHS is an increasing function, RHS is a decreasing function. It is clear that the solution is indeed unique if exists. Numerically at least we can do binary search.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is equivalent to $e^{-e}=(xe)^{-xe}$ .

For $y=z^{1/z}$ there is only one solution for $0<z<1$ because $(z^{1/z})'=z^{(1/z)-2}(1-\ln z)>0$ for $0<z<1$ means $z^{1/z}$ is strictly increasing for $0<z<1$.

With $y:=e^{-e}$ and $z:=(xe)^{-xe}$ one gets only one solution for $x$ which is obviously $1$.